# Uploading Files and Folder to Cpanel - Laravel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I am trying to upload my files onto cpanel now. Do i have add them manually?

Because i tried to copy the project folder into folder i created but then, i get an error trying to upload. Can any one here please give me a step to do this easily?

PS: It is my first time trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1 ) First compress your project and then upload to your cpanel

2 ) now go to your cpanel and extract the file and done.

Comment: @XamarinDevil if this answer is helpful to you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any FTP program with FTP credentials to upload project files. Just make sure you have appropriate permissions.

Also, you can upload the zip file as other answers suggest.

FTP programs

[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)